# getaliasesby command on SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias, data-warehouse

now im investigating SQL Query for making Datawarehouse.
I found this query on it :

```
MAX(dbo.GetAliasesByWo(b_1.wo_part, b_1.wo__dec01, RTRIM(LTRIM(b_1.wo__chr01)), RIGHT(RTRIM(LTRIM(b_1.wo_rmks)), 1))) AS list_wo, 
MAX(dbo.GetAliasesByWo1(b_1.wo_part, b_1.wo__dec01, RTRIM(LTRIM(b_1.wo__chr01)), RIGHT(RTRIM(LTRIM(b_1.wo_rmks)), 1))) AS list_wo1, 
MAX(dbo.GetAliasesByWo2(b_1.wo_part, b_1.wo__dec01, RTRIM(LTRIM(b_1.wo__chr01)), RIGHT(RTRIM(LTRIM(b_1.wo_rmks)), 1))) AS list_wo2
```

did anyone knows whats the meaning ? could you explain to me ?

Comment: Not unless you get can tell us what the functions `GetAliasesByWo`, `GetAliasesByWo1` and `GetAliasesByWo2` do, or provide their SQL; how do we know what a user function does we have no knowledge of? You'll also want to supply some sample data.

Comment: you have 3 user defined functions (scalar functions, according to their use in the query) if you want to keep investigating what these function are doing either see their definition or use the sp_helptext.

Comment: @Lamu yeah thx now i know thats related to function....

Comment: @hkravitz thx bruh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sp_helptext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql) command to view the definition.I think the given `GetAliasesByWo` is an user-defined function you can check the definititon with the below query:

```
EXEC [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_helptext 'dbo.GetAliasesByWo'
```

Comment: oh yeah thx .... i didnt know bout the function ... now i understand ... i check both of function and see this ... thanks a lot bruh.....

Comment: if you got your answer please accept this answer!!